# Why is MySQL Access denied after .bashrc edit?

Tags: mysql

I added this line

```
#mysql password
alias mysql='mysql -umilenko -p*myrealpass*** -hlocalhost'
```

Anyway,it does not work

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'milenko'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Also

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Version

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

I am not admin,I just need to use sql for my project.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never put *your* password into *any* script.
The accepted way to do this for MySQL is with a configuration file.

- Use a separate configuration file to hold the password.
- Protect that file so that you are the only one that can access it.
- alias mysql to use that configuration file.

Something like this:

```
$ ls -ld ~/.milenko.cnf 
-rw------- 1 ... ~/.milenko.cnf 

$ cat ~/.milenko.cnf 
[mysql]
username=milenko
password=REALPASSWORD
```

In .bash_profile

```
alias mysql="/usr/lib/mysql --defaults-extra-file=~/.milenko.cnf --umilenko hlocalhost"
```

[Related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205180/how-to-pass-password-to-mysql-command-line).

Answer (score 1):

Or...

First set up a configuration for each user:

```
$ mysql_config_editor set -G somename -u user -p -h localhost
```

(The `-p` will prompt for the password; it will not show up again.)

Set up this alias in their `.bashrc`:

```
alias mysql_somename="mysql --login-path=somename"
```

This will invoke MySQL with the user and pwd given.

```
$ mysql_somename
```

(There is chatter about how secure the encryption that mysq_config_editor provides.  I'm not addressing that.  The pwd is not in plaintext nor does it need to be re-entered.)